How can I trace a React app to find why it's crashing?
I have a React app that isn't working.  To be exact, it starts properly when I run it under npm's dev server, and runs to the point that it needs to access a database.  At that point it fails because the database isn't visible to the npm server.  To get to the database I need to run this app using an Xampp server -- but when I try to do that, the app fails completely.  It doesn't throw an error.  It doesn't output anything to the console or developer tools.  It just doesn't work.
As best I can tell, the application gets as far as the main App() function, and then ends without doing anything more.  It's supposed to call a login window, but it doesn't.  I didn't write this app and I'm not familiar with React so I have no idea what to do next, or where to look for the error.  I only know it works under npm, and fails under Xampp.
Is there a way to trace the app step-by-step, so that I can tell where it's failing?

xampp cannot run nodejs apps.

So you can't use Xampp as a dev environment for ReactJS applications at all?  Then what server package can I use?

Then what server package can I use? Well, nodejs. You can use the MySQL-server provided by xampp, you just can't use httpd for your server side app.


Check the Network Requests

Since the app is trying to access a database, there might be network requests being blocked or failing:
Check the network tab in Developer Tools to see if any requests are failing.
If your React app is trying to reach an API on a different origin, ensure that CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) is properly configured on your server by including the react app origin in the CORS settings origins field.

Running on XAMPP:

If your attempt to run your application on XAMPP fails totally. Try running npm run build on the app, then move the static files in the /build directory created directly into the folder you wish to use to access your application through /xampp/htdocs/ in order to serve the static index.html.

Check PORT Numbers:

Since your database is on a XAMPP server, you could confirm that the port number on which the database server is being run on XAMPP is not the same with the specified port your react app is running on in XAMPP.

Check for Environment Variables

Different environments might require different environment variables:
Ensure that any environment variables required for connecting to the database are correctly set in the XAMPP environment.
If the app relies on environment variables for API endpoints or database connections, make sure they are correctly set up in XAMPP.
